# How to manage many hosts with shipyard

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I am trying to use **shipyard** and mostly I am trying to manage many different hosts in one UI. 
But I can't find a way to make shipyard use existing swarm token.
Is there any way to add hosts to shipyard or it is for one host only ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**.

I solved it by editing the **shipyard deployment** script. Also I added parameter, to easily specify swarm token. The **shipyard-proxy** is no more used.

I also recommend to be attentive when specifying port for **docker daemon**, because one of the **shipyard** containers can try to use the **standard 2375** port.

I made **gist** with my code on GitHub. [Link to gist](https://gist.github.com/Lev09/8fcc562084a0b6b506d1).

My answer based on [discussion from GitHub](https://github.com/shipyard/shipyard/issues/599).